# Django many to many field with available app_labels

Tags: python, django

Hi is it possible for a model to have a ManyToManyField with all the available apps as its choices?

Let's say I have these apps on the INSTALLED_APPS in my settings.py

Then in my models.py I have this model

```
class IPAddreses(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    apps = models.ManyToManyField(ContentType, blank=True)
    # The apps field should be the choices of the avialable apps on the settings.py
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your use case?

Comment: To enable the IPAddress whitelisting on every app authentication

Comment: See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions

Answer (score 1):

Probably not possible, but what you can do is just have a new model/table that is updated with the list of installed apps, and add a many to many relationship to that model.
That would be a simpler and more flexible solution.
Since you could possibly keep track (if needed) of the relationships with apps that get removed from your installed apps list.

Comment: Thanks for the solution though.. But as much as possible I would avoid that because it is almost a hard-coded solution

Comment: You are welcome, but It doesn't have to be hard-coded. You can easily add some python code at the end of your settings.py code, so that it runs everytime your app is restarted, so that it runs every time your list of apps changes. In that code you just look for the apps from your installed list that are missing in your table and add them to your table, and you may also look for any that exists on your table that doesn't exist in your installed list to delete them or just flag them as logically deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
# models.py
class IPAddressApp(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    app = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ("ip", "app"),
        )

# forms.py
from django.apps import apps

class IPAddressAppForm(forms.ModelForm):
    app = forms.ChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.IPAddressApp
        fields = (
            'ip',
            'app',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['app'].choices = self.get_apps()

    def get_apps(self):
        return [(app, "{} ({})".format(config.verbose_name, app)) for
                app, config in apps.app_configs.items()]
```

Other options:

- For a Many-To-Many field, Use an `App` model and populate it using the code above on the app's [`ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method.
- Use `ArrayField(CharField)` ([Postgresql only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)) for apps.